# Force linq dbml file to get database values

Tags: linq-to-sql, instance

I have two sites, one administration site, where i can edit all the values in a database, and a public site that only reads the data from the database.
Both the site have identical dbml files to work on the databas.
When I insert a new car (Site is about cars, so all values are car related) and it's data, the inserted values display on the public site immediatly...
When I update data for a car, the values in the database are changed immediatly but the Public site keeps displaying the old values... 
I read that I can use a new instance of the dbml file for each query to force the dbml file to go read the values in the database...

I do this with the following code in a code file where I put al my queries... but this doesn't work...

```
 Public Shared AixamReader As FrontstoreAdministrationDataClassesDataContext = New FrontstoreAdministrationDataClassesDataContext
```

Then I call AixamReader in each Query...

Is there a better way to force the dbml file to get the updated values from a database?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your problem is not the DBML file. The DBML does not read or query your data, it is just a base for the generation of the classes that do the actual work.

So updating/inserting data in the actual database has zero effect on your DBML file.

I think what you are calling DMBL file here, is actually the DataContext.

And yes, if you use an "old"  DataContext to do your queries and in the meantime your data is updated by another process, it will not show up in the queries you do with that DataContext. This is also known as a "**stale datacontext**".

So, use a new DataContext for each request and your problem is solved. Anyway, DataContexts are pretty lightweight and are designed to be used this way (a new one for each unit of work).

Comment: This is something I already read in other comments. But apparently I'm not getting it right because I tought that with the code as shown in my post I get a new instance of my datacontext everytime. So where and how do I call a new instance of my datacontext then? Thx for the explenation.

Comment: Well, it is Public and Shared, so most probably you are reusing it? I always have a local variable with a Using() around it, but i am a C# person